# Issues with adding formula to cell through VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to understand how to add formulas to cells through VBA.

Currently, I'm trying a simple Sum function.

```
Cells(NewLastRowNumber, 2).Formula "=Sum(Range(Cells(NewLastRowNumber + 8, 3), Cells(LastRowNumber, 3)))"
```

All variable are defined well as the equation works if I use

```
Cells(NewLastRowNumber, 2).forumla = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(NewLastRowNumber + 8, 3), Cells(LastRowNumber, 3)))
```

How would I go about modifying my code to get Excel to display the formula in the cell? `NewLastRowNumber` will never be the predictable that will always depend on the data the user use's.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, I was told that they use the formula to quickly check the calcs are using the correct data

Comment: @pnuts I think he means showing the result *using* the formula as opposed to just the raw number, not actually showing the text of the formula in the cell

Comment: @dwirony yes that's what i meant. Mis understood your comment. Thanks

Comment: @pnuts It was a bit confusing! haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

vba needs to outside the `""` and concatenated with `&`.  You also need to return the address of the range.

```
Cells(NewLastRowNumber, 2).Formula = "=Sum(" & Range(Cells(NewLastRowNumber + 8, 3), Cells(LastRowNumber, 3)).Address(0,0) & ")"
```

But to be more thorough, one should always assign the parent sheet to any Range Objects.

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change to your sheet
    .Cells(NewLastRowNumber, 2).Formula = "=Sum(" & .Range(.Cells(NewLastRowNumber + 8, 3), .Cells(LastRowNumber, 3)).Address(0,0) & ")"
End With
```

Comment: Whenever I try and run this i get `Run TIme error 438 Object dosen't support this property or method` Any suggestions? Also what do you mean by Assigning the partent sheet to a range object? Is that just specifing which sheet?

Comment: Excellent. Thank you so very much :)

Comment: HI Scott, I was playingaround with your solution yesterday and ran across an issue whilst trying to subtract some cells, would oyu mind pointing out where i went wrong `With Worksheets(c10)
    .Cells(NewEngineRowNumber + 3, 2).Formula = "=Sum((" & .Range(.Cells(NewEngineRowNumber + 6, 2)).Address(0, 0) & ") - (" & .Range(.Cells(NewEngineRowNumber + 2, 2)).Address(0, 0) & "))"
End With` Thats is my code, which as far as I can see if the most logical method to get subtract working. Thanks

Comment: I am away today. Please ask a new question. You can reference this one. You will get quicker help.